# PHP mail has empty body under certain conditions

Tags: php, html, email

Okay, I have built the following function and I'm using it for quite a while now:

```
/**
 * Sends an HTML e-mail with attachments
 *
 * @param  string $mailto       the e-mail receiver
 * @param  string $from_mail    the sender e-mail
 * @param  string $from_name    the sender name
 * @param  string $subject      the e-mail subject line
 * @param  string $messageText  the message
 * @param  array $files        the filenames (with path)
 * @param  string $replyto      where replies should be send
 * @param  boolean $isPlain if the message should be send as plain text and not html
 * @return boolean $success TRUE if the mail has been send
 */
function mail_attachment($mailto, $from_mail, $from_name, $subject, $messageText, $files = array(), $replyto = '', $isPlain = FALSE, $charset='iso-8859-1') {
    if ($replyto == '') {
        $replyto = $from_mail;
    }
    $messageType = ($isPlain ? 'plain' : 'html');
    $boundary = '==Multipart_Boundary_x' . md5(uniqid(time())) . 'x';
    $header  = 'From: ' . $from_name . ' <' . $from_mail . '>' . LF;
    $header .= 'Reply-To: ' . $replyto . LF;
    $header .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . LF ;
    $header .= 'Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="' . $boundary . '"';
    $message = 'This is a multi-part message in MIME format' . LF . LF;
    $message .= '--' . $boundary . LF;
    $message .= 'Content-Type: text/' . $messageType . '; charset="' . $charset . '"' . LF;
    $message .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit' . LF . LF;
    $message .= $messageText . LF . LF;
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        if (is_file($file)) {
            $message .= '--' . $boundary . LF;
            $name = basename($file);
            $file_size = filesize($file);
            $type = substr(strrchr($file, "."), 1);;
            $handle = fopen($file, "r");
            $content = fread($handle, $file_size);
            fclose($handle);
            $content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
            $message .= 'Content-Type: application/' . $type . '; name="' . $name . '"' . LF; // use different content types here
            $message .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64' . LF ;
            $message .= 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $name . '"' . LF . LF;
            $message .= $content . LF . LF;
        }
    }
    $message .= '--' . $boundary . '--';

    return mail($mailto, $subject, $message, $header);
}
```

Now I used in on an intranet system, where a monthly cronjob should send individual html mails to a little more than 400 users. I tested it with just replacing the selected receiver with my own adress and I got all 400 mails with the individual content.
I also tested it with a condition that send the e-mail only if the name was in a whitelist, to be sure if they get through the internal systems.
All went well, until the final release. Now all 400 recipients got an empty e-mail with just the subject and the header.

Now I'm thinking about storing all the mails in a temporary table and selecting small bunches out of it with another cronjob (like every 5 minutes) that sends them.

Do you have an explanation for what happened and maybe another solution?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Don't build your own mime email. Use swiftmailer or phpmailer. both of which will reduce most of that mime-building code to just a few method calls.

Comment: @Marc B:Thank you for your advice. I'll look into swiftmailer tomorrow. I'd like to know what the actual problem with my solution is though, since I'm trying to learn something here ;)